# Sex with centaurs can be considered bestiality?

Tags: mythical-creatures, medieval, alternate-reality, sex, social-norms

Lets say centaurs were created by proto-humans that had sex with zebras in ancient Africa. They lived in migrating herds but now they are integrated in human kingdoms. However some humans wanted to marry and have sexual relationships with them. Could be considered bestiality and taboo?

PS : Humans and centaurs cannot reproduce now. It was an opportunistic evolution move. Humans and centaurs have the same intellectual capacity.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense that humans and zebras could interbreed, but humans and centaurs cannot.

Comment: @kingledion ALTERNATE -REALITY,Please stop being picky with questions,We all know writing is not easy and sometimes doesnt have logic. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I want to run into spider-man in this reality....

Comment: There are at least three definitions of bestiality in real life, and this is your world, so it can use any of them, or have any other. Your opinion only.

Comment: I want to remind you of the existing [Sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) to test how posts will be received by the community and thereby drastically decreasing the chance of it getting put on hold.

Comment: A world with multiple species with the same intellectual capacity of humans would have a drastically different opinions on what are beasts/animals to what we do (i.e. basically all non-humans). Centaurs and humans probably trade & interact socially. So yeah there could be a big taboo, or it could even be illegal or dangerous, but the word "bestiality" is probably not appropriate.

Comment: @kingledion Not necessarily. A horse and a donkey can interbreed, but their offspring are generally infertile. Not quite the same thing but it shows how such funny things can happen at a genetic level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, no. Bestiality is more along the lines of having relationships with a creature incapable of understanding what is going on.

HOWEVER.

It could EASILY be taboo and shunned. There are points in history where people having relationships with people outside a very narrow social group was considered Very Bad, and it's somewhat around today. And not just in skin color - Caste systems have used it. Feudal systems frowned upon mixing of class, etc.

Comment: So, sex with a willing ape or monkey isn't bestiality? These are capable of understanding, to the point of having prostitution.

Comment: @Molot Primates capable of prostitution with humans? I'd like to see a citation for that before commenting.

Comment: @a4android I meant prostitution between each other. Orangutans and chimpanzee knows what prostitution is, what sex for pleasure is. With humans? There is a debate if the examples that really happened were prostitution, sex slavery or animal abuse. Google for "orangutan Pony" if you must, I won't link that.

Answer (score 4):

The truth of the matter is, due to lack of inteligent non-humans, there is no real boundary set for what constitutes Bestiality. There are technical definitions, but most people are unaware of them, and as such they might as well not exist.

I will try to outline some commonly held beliefs as to what constitutes bestiality, so that you can decide, where along that line, the people of your world will draw the line.

### Racial purity reasoning:

Sex with any non-human is bestiality. Including sex with other inteligent beings. (For historical context: Sex with black slaves was at times considered bestiality.)

### ICK-Factor reasoning:

Sex with any animal is bestiality. This is different from other versions, in that "Animal" is only defined by "common sense". This variation is entirely dependent on emotional reasoning.

### Transhuman reasoning:

Sex with any non-thinking creature is bestiality. This one of the more commonly accepted liberal interpretations.

### Extreme Transhuman reasoning

Sex with  any creature that isn't able to consent is bestiality. A very slight variation of the above reasoning; It is the kind of reasoning you will sometimes find among real life zoophilia groups.

Answer (score 1):

Bestiality is more or less defined as "the act of having sexual intercourse with animals".

This clearly marks human-centaur intercourses as bestiality.

But this in our reality. You can very well set your own rules, stating for example that sex is by long used as a way to strengthen relationships between groups, therefore in this case it can be socially accepted or even encouraged.

Comment: Anywhere I look for bestiality's definition I read "sex between a person and an animal" (said in different ways).

Comment: @AlbertMasclans, I had in mind a more religiously biased definition. I edited my answer to fit the definition you provided